# What are some exercises for glutes and iliopsas that don't require equipment?

Tags: strength-training, sprinting, lower-body-strength

As mentioned in a previous question I am a 100/200m sprinter. I have, what I consider to be, a strong body for my sport (stats at the bottom of the post).

Two muscle groups that I am looking to improve are my glutes (my bottom) and my iliopsoas (hip flexors). I think that these two specific muscle groups are instrumental in a fast sprinting speed.

Does anybody have any decent exercises for these muscles groups. Bare in mind that I currently do not have access to an olympic bar, so no dead lifting etc at the moment.

Thanks in advanced

**Stats**

> 6Ft, 83kg weight
>
> 95kg Bench press (machine not free)
>
> 250kg Leg press (gym max, machine not free, 2 legged. 1 leg 140kg right, 130kg left.)
>
> **All repped at 3 x 10**

Comment: Iliopsoas: http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/Iliopsoas.html

Comment: Funny you said no olympic bars... Squats, Deadlifts, and Cleans are all excellent tools to build up the posterior chain and build explosive power.  The cleans, esp. work for explosive power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple body weight exercises that can help your Glutes and Iliopsas.  Unfortunately for one of them you still need some equipment.

**Iliopsas:**

- Situps (can be performed weighted)
- Front kicks/Round house kicks (only perform body weight, and do both)

**Glutes:**

- Squats (can be performed body weight or weighted with dumbbells or barbells)
- Side kicks (only perform body weight)
- [Back extensions](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/ErectorSpinae/WtBackExtension.html) (can be performed weighted)
- [Bird Dogs](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/ErectorSpinae/BWBirdDog.html)

In fact, exrx.net has a [number of exercises](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/HipsWt.html) that target the areas you are looking at.

Answer (score 2):

**Hip thrusts**
Best for glutes and some hamstring involvement, this movement works on a horizontal plane.

**Cable standing leg raise**
Great r.o.m. for hip flexors, can also be done with ankle weights, rubber band or rubber tubing this also works on a horizontal plane.

These two exercises are a great start to strengthening key muscles for the 100/200 meter sprint, if you can make it to a gym **G.H.R, back extensions, deadlifts and olympic style squats** are a must.

- Quads are for acceleration.
- Hamstrings and glutes are for top speed.
- Hip flexors help in both stages.

Final words: There are two ends of the performance spectrum, strength and speed. If your fast work strength, staying in the low reps - high set area always progressively loading your exercises. Stay fast my friends.